# url rewrite and google robots txt

Tags: php, security, seo, url-rewriting, robots.txt

I use php slim framework, with url rewrite here is my host real file structure:
like most framework all **rewrite to index.php**

```
/.htaccess
/assets
/index.php
/phpinfo.php
/robots.txt
/usr
    /controller
    /model
    ...
```

and here is my router

```
$app->get('/backstage', $authenticate(), function () use ($uri, $app) {...});
$app->get('/api', $authenticate(), function () use ($uri, $app) {...});

$app->get('/', function () use ($uri, $app) {...});
$app->get('/article', function () use ($uri, $app) {...});
```

How to disable `/backstage`, `/api` in my route,   and real file path `/phpin.php`, `/usr`,
And accept `/`, `/article` in router?

I'm confusing should I fill router path or real file path? because real file path there is not exist `/article`

and this is I tried

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /backstage/
Disallow: /phpinfo.php
```

Answer (score 1):

First *(assuming you use apache)*, you need to make sure your *.htaccess* file correctly points requests to your router file.

--- begin .htaccess snippet ---

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    
    ## direct all requests to Slim router
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ slim-router.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

--- end .htaccess snippet ---

I may not be understanding your question properly, but to disable a route, simply comment out the line in *slim-router.php* that adds the route.

Adding entries to *robots.txt* will not prevent browsers from reaching a URI, it only exists to ask search engine bots *(i.e., [GoogleBot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182072?hl=en))* to not index that particular URI.  See [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) and [the robots.txt entry on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard).

To direct a route to an existing file, you can use the `\Slim\View` class *(see [the `\Slim\View` documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/#View-Overview))*.
This example expects a file named *templates/article.php* to exist, which is the file that will output the content for the `/article` route.
Using the `\Slim\View` class, you can also send data to the template file, which I have demonstrated below as well.  This is only a basic example, see the documentation for more complex usage.

//--- begin slim-router.php ---

```
    $app = new \Slim\Slim();
    $defview = new \Slim\View();
    $defview->setTemplatesDirectory(realpath(__DIR__).'/templates');

    $app->get(
        '/article',
        function () use ($app) {
          global $defview;
          //show the contents of 'templates/article.php', passing optional data to the template file:
          $app->view($defview)->display(
              'article.php', 
              array(
                 'data_one'=>'one',
                 'data_two'=>2,
                 'three'=>'3',
              )
          );
        }
    );
```

//--- end slim-router.php ---